# Обязательное выполнение переопределенного метода родителькосго класса

Tags: c++, наследование, переопределение

Можно ли как то заставить компилятор сигнализировать об ошибке, если не вызван метод родительского класса, либо каким то другим образом контроллировать это?

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void func() { printf("base\n"); };
};

class Class1 : public Base
{
public:
    Class1() {};
    void func() { printf("class1\n"); } ;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оборачиваем вызов виртуальной функции в обычный с предварительным выполнением обязательного действия:

```
class Base
{
    private: virtual void func_impl() {}
    public: void func() { printf("base\n"); func_impl(); }
};

class Class1 : public Base
{
    private: void func_impl() override { printf("class1\n"); }
};
```

Более хитрый вариант, требующий, что некоторый метод из базового класса будет вызван в дочернем классе посредством передачи объекта-токена:

```
class Base
{
    protected: class InvocationToken final
    {
        friend class Base;
        private: InvocationToken() {}
    };
    protected: virtual InvocationToken func_impl() { printf("base\n"); return InvocationToken{}; }
    public: void func() { func_impl(); }
};

class Class1 : public Base
{
    private: InvocationToken func_impl() override
    {
        auto token{Base::func_impl()};
        printf("class1\n");
        return token;
    }
};
```

Comment: А если вызов базового метода должен идти в одном наследнике между действиями в методе наследника, в другом - до, в третьем - после?...

Comment: @Harry Если логика в наследниках сложная, то можно добавить соотв. флажок  и выполнять пост проверку, вызвался ли требуемый метод или нет. Или разделить виртуальный метод на три стадии и вставлять вызов "обязательного действия" между ними.

Comment: Да, но этот способ - флажок и проверка - не соответствует запросу - автоматическому требованию вызова. Просто мне кажется, что в общем случае эта задача неразрешима...

Comment: @Harry Добавил более хитрый вариант с передачей токена.